# Run npm build script in bash script file

Tags: bash, npm, cron, gatsby, npm-scripts

I have deployed a gatsby.js website in AWS s3 server and I wanted to add a crontab for running `npm run build` at certain intervals. The crontab is working fine (I have tested it with several other commands) however it seems to fail on the npm script run

The contents of the `build-script.sh` are:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/local/bin/npm
cd /var/www/my-website
npm run-script build
```

Both `npm run-script build` and `npm run build` failed. Is there any particular reason for this?

Edit: after suggestion I tried adding the full path to npm (didn't work)
Also, running the command manually from the bash `bash build-script.sh` works and outputs the expected result.

Update: after logging the failing command (`npm run build`) I get `usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory`

Comment: I suggest to add full path to `npm`.

Comment: I have also tried it but no result.

Comment: Maybe you can find npm executable and add; `pathToNPM.sh run build`

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Could you provide an example?

Comment: You can run `which npm`, you will get back something like `/usr/local/bin/npm`, then you can write something like `/usr/local/bin/npm run build` to execute gatsby build

Comment: Nop, didn't work